# Как автоматически банить ip-адреса?

Tags: ipfw, freebsd

Всем привет Сегодня с этого адреса 89.175.165.150 поступало по 5 запросов в секунду. Сервер чуть не упал.Написал правило add deny all from 89.175.165.150 to me и фаервол заблокировал его.Но как написать такое правило, чтобы ipfw Автоматически блокировал такие ip-адреса?

Comment: Я давно уже не занимался фаерволом во FreeBSD, поэтому просто посоветую посмотреть [сюда][1] в частности на секцию 28.6.5.1.5 Отбор. Там есть опция: > limit {src-addr | src-port | dst-addr> | dst-port}которая скорее всего вам поможет.  [1]: http://www.lissyara.su/doc/docs/handbook_-_ipfw/

Comment: Написал вот такое правило:add allow tcp from any to me setup limit src-addr 50Как вы думаете оно действительно ограничет количество соединений с одного айпишника?Не знаю как правильно add allow tcp или может быть add allow ipСпасибо.

Comment: tcp если вам важен tcp, ip, если вы хотите ограничивать все семейство протоколов ip.Проверить можно указав число 2, например, и открыв с помощью telnet 3 сессии к 80 порту, если у вас там http поднят с другой машины.Так же советую вам указать порт, для которого будет работать это правило и интерфейс.

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую.

Answer (score 4):

Поставьте fail2ban, он заблокирует по настроенным правилам.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Странный вопрос.На чтении документации к этому пакету, т.к. он предназначен для блокировки нежелательных соединений.

Comment: Было бы здорово увидеть ваше экспертное мнение в более развернутом ответе.